# Porque usar Wordpress en lugar de crear tu propio sitio

Tags: wordpress

Quiero hacer un blog, y con el tiempo añadirle funcionalidades como monetización, SEO entre otras cosas. Recientemente he visto que Wordpress esta tomando buena reputación en el mercado, cuando desde mi perspectiva podría ser un software empaquetado que llegue a limitarme en las funcionalidades que quiero agregar en el futuro.
Una de las principales dudas que tengo es como añadiría la monetización si uso esta herramienta y si esta cobraría alguna comisión.

Comment: Creo que te respondes en tu propia pregunta: **podría ser un software empaquetado que llegue a limitarme en las funcionalidades**.

Comment: ¿Acaso con WordPress no estarías también creando tu sitio?

Comment: Bien, una de las principales dudas que tengo es como añadiría la monetización si uso esta herramienta y si esta cobraría alguna comision

Comment: Tal vez porque no tienes que invertir un montón de tiempo programando todo, y existen un montón de plugins que te facilitan la vida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress te permite arrancar rápidamente sin la necesidad de tener muchos conocimientos, aunque como tu bien has dicho "puede limitarte".

> Cuando desde mi perspectiva podría ser un software empaquetado que
>   llegue a limitarme en las funcionalidades que quiero agregar en el
>   futuro.

Si no tienes prisa, tomate tu tiempo en hacer tu sitio nativo y a medida que vas avanzando, lo vas adaptando a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress te permite enfocarte en la creación de contenidos sin tener que invertir mucho tiempo en diseño y programación , integración con una base de datos,te dedicas a los contenidos por eso puedes ganar mucho tiempo.